# How to display flash messages from an ajax form submission?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

In a Rails 3.2 app I have a form that is submitted via Ajax, with feedback provided to the user via flash messages.

There are two (or more?) ways to approach this.

I could define `format js` in the controller and then reload the flash message partial

```
#template.js.erb
`$(".flash-container").html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'shared/flash_messages') %>");`
```

Or I could render the flash html from a jquery function (e.g. [this](https://gist.github.com/linjunpop/3410235)).

My question is, are there any advantages or disadvantages to either approach?

I understand how the jquery function works, but I don't (yet) fully understand what is happening in Rails internals using the js approach. Is there are performance impact with one over the other?

Is one approach considered more "Railsy" than than the other?

I'm keen to learn how others would approach this, and which is the preferred approach.

Comment: do you have the first method working?

Answer (score 0):

in your controller create

```
respond_to do |format|
    format.js { render 'your_js_file' }
end
```

and like wise what you have in your js.erb to render is the best way to do what your doing.

1: Its the most common way and other people who read your code will better understand whats going on. I have seen it done this way a few time by many people, so right a way I under stand how it works. "KISS"

2: As for the second method you shown it is nice "looking" but since you lack to understand it just yet and feel the need to debug it that tells you about its read ability which should hold just as much weight as how cool the code looks. Think about this way if your having to debug it so will anyone else who reads your code too.

Some times the best way, is the way you know how.

Comment: thanks Digital Cake. I have the first method working. The second I don't really need to debug, more modify to fit my application. What I'm wonder is, are there any e.g. performance considerations or other advantages/ disadvantages to either approach, or do they essentially do the same thing in different ways? Good point about KISS and doing things the "rails" way